# Predict PHP rand() by having many outputs of it

Tags: php, security, random

I was wondering if it possible to predict the next pseudo random number that will be generated out of PHP rand() function, by using the previous outputs of it.

An example would be that I have n outputs of rand(1,10) like 8, 5, 10, 3, 3, 2 ... 9, 8 ... and so on.

So the question is, is there any way that I can use these already generated numbers to predict the next one?

**EDIT**

Since the question was marked as too broad, I will try to be more specific. Can I predict the next RGN or recover the seed, on PHP running on Linux, when using the rand() function, by only observing some outputs given from it.

A concrete example is the following output:

> 21962
>
> 10038
>
> 10425
>
> 17032

Generated by the following code:

```
<?php
echo rand(1, 68703);
```

Comment: [Cracking Random Number Generators](https://jazzy.id.au/2010/09/22/cracking_random_number_generators_part_3.html) and related articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is under the hood, but it is likely covered by one of these links:

- cracking php's php_mt_rand: https://github.com/bishopfox/untwister
- cracking php's lcg_value: http://www.crypto-world.com/lcg_value.html

If it is not covered, then provide me the source code and I will break it.

**EDIT**: As requested in comments below, I update my answer.

One trivial way to break it is brute force search of the srand seed. Normally this is a 32-bit int (which will take a few minutes to brute force), but on some platforms it may be 64-bit (takes too long to break via brute force). So you just loop through each candidate seed, do srand( candidate seed) and then generate your rand(1, 68703) to see if it matches the outputs. If so, you presumably have the right seed and can generate future outputs. Otherwise continue loop.

Comment: Thanks for the sources, but for some reasons I couldn't manage to run the Untwister project, anyway I will look into it. I also updated the question with the concrete example that I am looking on.

Comment: @TrimKadriu One trivial way to break it is brute force search of the srand seed.  Normally this is a 32-bit int (which will take a few minutes to brute force), but on some platforms it may be 64-bit (takes too long to break via brute force).  So you just loop through each candidate seed, do srand( candidate seed) and then generate your rand(1, 68703) to see if it matches the outputs.  If so, you presumably have the right seed and can generate future ouputs.  Otherwise continue loop.  Make sense?

Comment: Totally makes sense! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I managed to crack it very simply with brute-force in just few seconds. I would suggest to update your answer with your comment above.